# Problemas a atualizar do token de acesso

Tags: java, rest, oauth, oauth2, google-calendar

Estou a fazer a autenticação à API do Google Calendar usando o Scribe, que por usa vez usa o OAuth 2.0. A autenticação é concluída com sucesso mas não sei como guardar o token de acesso (accessToken) na base de dados. Estou a fazer o seguinte:

```
/*Obter o API USER TOKEN e o API USE SECRET*/
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
API_USER_TOKEN = accessToken.getToken();
API_USER_SECRET = accessToken.getSecret();
/*Guardar tudo na base de dados*/
saveToken(API_USER_TOKEN, API_USER_SECRET);
```

Depois preciso de ir buscar o token e usá-lo novamente e é aqui que aparecem os problemas, como é que volto a construir o token que guardei na base de dados ?
E como é que actualizo o token ?

Para atualizar o token estou a tentar usar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
request.addQuerystringParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
request.addQuerystringParameter("refresh_token", oldToken.getToken());
request.addQuerystringParameter("client_id", API_APP_KEY);
request.addQuerystringParameter("client_secret", API_APP_SECRET);
service.signRequest(oldToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
```

Mas obtenho sempre o mesmo erro ( resposta da google api ): `invalid_grant Bad Request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu erro está nessa linha:

```
request.addQuerystringParameter("refresh_token", oldToken.getToken());
```

O token que você precisa usar para gerar um novo par é o refresh token, e não o access token.

Comment: Como obtenho o refresh token ?

Comment: Não sei como é a  implementação Java, mas sei que, de acordo com o protocolo OAuth V2, quando você requisita um Access Token, você recebe não só o mesmo como também um Refresh Token, para usá-lo quando o Access Token expirar. Você deve, então, armazenar o Refresh Token e usá-lo no parâmetro `refresh_token`.

Comment: @AndréLizardo Fiz algumas implementações com a API do Google Drive e a [documentação exemplifica como obter o Refresh Token](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server#authenticate_the_user). Em resumo, o token é obtido na primeira vez que o usuário autoriza o acesso da sua aplicação. Você deve armazená-lo para uso posterior.